# CSS3 - Is 'grid' only for Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css

I am watching the [Microsoft Virtual Academy](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/learn-html5-with-javascript-css3-jumpstart-training) videos as a way to prepare for MS exam 70-480. In it they discuss flexbox and grids (using only MS-prefixed attributes).
I can see flexbox working, as it is implemented by IE, Firefox and Chrome. But Grid does not appear to work with anything other than IE.
If I go to the excellent [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/g/grid/) website the demos there won't work with Firefox nor Chrome, only IE.

Are grids IE-specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grid layout is a W3C specification working draft: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/

It doesn't seem to be supported in any other browser but IE at the moment though: http://caniuse.com/#search=grid

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it started in IE, but there are issues opened in [Webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60731) and [Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=616605) bugtracker. You can read more about grid [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/04/14/ie10-platform-preview-and-css-features-for-adaptive-layouts.aspx) if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not Microsoft is ahead of the curve on grid implementation. So much so that a WINjs uses it as a foundation. They have stated they are committed to adjust their implemented grid & flexbox model as the standard becomes ratified. The other browsers are dragging thier feet on this implementation as the group can't come to a decsion of the spec for browser makers.